# Python : Mockey Patch Leaking to Other unit test cases

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, fastapi, monkeypatching

Here is my unit test case written using monkey patch library in python :

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_my_method(monkeypatch):
    app.dependency_overrides[check_token] = override_token_expired

    async def mock_cosmos_query(*args, **kwargs):   
        return fake_spaces    

    monkeypatch.setattr('app.routers.space.cosmos_query', mock_cosmos_query)    
    response = client.get("/api/spaces/TestSpace",  headers={"authorization": "fake user"}, params={"expand": "false"})

    jsonObj = response.json()
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert jsonObj['name'] == 'TestSpace'  
    monkeypatch.undo() // NOT WORKING
```

The problem is that when I do monkeypatch.undo(), it doesn't undo monkeypatch.setattr() and hence rest of my test cases fails.

My expectation is that when I do monkeypatch.undo(), it should reset monkeypatch and the bahviour of monkey patch do not leak to other test cases.

Can someone please guid me here ?

Comment: Did this test pass, or fail?

Comment: This one is passing but the behavior is leaking to other test cases. I want to undo this "monkeypatch.setattr('app.routers.space.cosmos_query', mock_cosmos_query) "  once the test case is completed.

Comment: That's strange, because monkeypatch is supposed to undo itself automatically, too, even if you don't call `undo`. If I were you, I'd put `assert app.routers.space.cosmos_query is not mock_cosmos_query` after your call to `undo`, just to make sure of if `undo` is working or not.